# How to wait until a widget gets loaded in flutter integration test?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-integration-test

Is there any way in flutter integration test keeping wait until a widget gets loaded completely?

Like waiting until the home page is loaded after finishing the splash screen?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `await tester.pumpAndSettle()`, it awaits every animation to end before going to the next step. For more info you can look at the docs in [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pumpAndSettle.html) link.